# React showing two component at a single time

Tags: reactjs

I am having 2 routes and 2 component like

```
<Route path=`/admin/login/` exact  component={Login} />
<Route path="/admin/:file?/:id?"  component={Main} />
```

when i am having http://localhost:3000/admin/login i just want to show the Login component but it's showing both component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows the second route too because it thinks that parameter ':file?' is the '/login', for this thing Switch exist(just like switch statements, it chooses only one route):

`import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path=`/admin/login/`exact  component={Login} />
        <Route path="/admin/:file?/:id?" exact component={Main} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>`

Comment: Do i need to use switch instead of BrowserRouter

Comment: @vivekmodi you can use `Switch` inside `BrowserRouter`

Comment: u need both, browser router is to init routing in your app(every react a5pp is wrapped by it first), then add switch and then route

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj can you give me example of switch inside BrowserRouter

Comment: sorry for bad formmating im in phone going to sleep but i hope u get thw idea

Answer (score 0):

If the `exact` doesn't work.

Maybe did try to send `file` and and `id` for props or save that in the `async storage`.

Another way you could change the route like

```
<Route path="/admin/main" exact component={Main} />
```